# Floating small view of image in GIMP single-window mode?

Tags: gimp

If I'm editing a small image in GIMP, I'd zoom in as far as I need to, with a separate view (creating through **View > New View**) at 1x zoom level so that I could see what it looks like at normal size as I draw.

In 2.8 I prefer single-window mode, except new views are stuck as just another image tab, so I can't see both views at once. Is there some way of achieving this within single-window mode?

Answer (score 1):

I've half-solved my own problem by using the Navigation dialogue, and undocking that. It's not ideal because I'd like the small view to be at 100% and there's a limit to how small you can make the floating Navigation window. Still open to improvements on this workaround.

[image: Using Navigator tab as a small view]

Comment: You want the small view to be 100 percent of what? Near as I can tell, in that screenshot you just posted, the navigation dialog is at 3200 percent, not 100.

Comment: The 3200% refers to the main viewport, so changing that zooms the main view in and out. The smaller image in the navigation dialog is sized to fit the space available in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the navigation dialog separately ( by dragging it from the right side-bar into the workspace so that it becomes a stand-alone window) and resize it until it seems large enough. Hope this helps ( workesd perfectly fine for me)